# Create a stack model with the package mlr3

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr3

I'm using the `mlr3pipelines` package to It define a pipeline object named "stack" which is used for stacking ensemble learning.

However, I'm unable to find an alternative to the 'po' function, it's not suitable for stacking models as I get this error:

```
Error: Element with key 'stack' not found in DictionaryPipeOp!
```

What is a good way to create stacking?

Here is the code whole code if it helps:

```
super_train <- function(data, n_models = 10, cpus = 32) {


  train <- as.data.table(data[[1]])
  test <- as.data.table(data[[2]])
        
  task <- TaskClassif$new(id = "my_task", backend = train, target = "CR")
  
  base_learners <- lapply(1:n_models, function(i) {
    lrn_lgbm <- lrn("classif.lightgbm", predict_type = "response", objective = "binary")
    lrn_lgbm$param_set$values$num_iterations <- 1000 # set a large number of trees
    lrn_lgbm$param_set$values$early_stopping_rounds <- 50 # early stopping
    lrn_lgbm$param_set$values$verbose <- -1 # suppress lightGBM's output
    lrn_lgbm
  })
  
  meta_learners <- lapply(1:n_models, function(i) {
    lrn_rf <- lrn("classif.randomForest", predict_type = "response", mtry = 3, ntree = 500, importance = "gini")
    return(lrn_rf)
  })
  
  base_resampling <- rsmp("cv", folds = 10)
  
  # set up stacking
  stack <- mlr3pipelines::po(.obj = "stack", base_learners = base_learners, metalearner = lrn("classif.gam"))
  
  # set up stacking resampling
  stack_resampling <- rsmp("cv", folds = 10)
  
  ps_lgbm <- ParamSet$new(params = list(
    makeDiscreteParam("booster", values = c("gbtree","gblinear")), 
    makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.01, upper = 0.06), 
    makeIntegerParam("max_depth", lower = 3L, upper = 10L), 
    makeNumericParam("min_child_weight", lower = 2L, upper = 8L), 
    makeNumericParam("subsample", lower = 0.5, upper = 0.5), 
    makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree", lower = 0.5, upper = 0.8)
  ))
  
  
  # set up hyperparameters tuning
  base_tuning <- tune_grid(
    base_learners,
    task,
    resampling = base_resampling,
    measure = msr("classif.auc"),
    control = ctrl_tuning(
      method = "random",
      repeats = 10,
      show_info = FALSE,
      save_pred = "none"
    ),
    par.set = ps_lgbm
  )
  
  base_models <- lapply(base_tuning$learners, function(lrn) {
    train(lrn, task)
  })
  
  # train the meta-learners
  meta_models <- lapply(meta_learners, function(lrn) {
    train(stack, task, stack_resampling)
  })
  
  best_meta_model <- meta_models[[which.max(sapply(meta_models, function(m) m$aggregated_result$score))]]
  
  best_base_models <- lapply(base_models, function(m) m$learner)
  final_model <- stack$train(best_base_models, best_meta_model, task)
        
  return(final_model)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of dictionaries from which you can retrieve objects to define graphs:

- `PipeOp`s can be retrieved using the `po()` function. See an overview [here](https://mlr-org.com/pipeops.html)
- Predefined `Graph`s can be retrieved using the `ppl()` function. See an overview [here](https://mlr-org.com/graphs.html)

You seem to be looking for the graph that can be retrieved using `ppl("stacking")`. Its manual page can be found [here](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_graphs_stacking.html).